# Processing presentation from XBRL taxonomy

Tags: xbrl

I'm trying to parse presentation files from XBRL taxonomy.
This is an extract from file where I have trouble:

```
<presentationLink xlink:type="extended" xlink:role="http://www.infocamere.it/itnn/fr/itcc/role/NotaIntegrativaAttivo">
  <presentationArc xlink:type="arc" xlink:arcrole="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/arcrole/parent-child" xlink:from="itcc-ci_AttivitaOperazioniLocazioneFinanziariaLocatario" xlink:to="itcc-ci_ContrattiCorsoOperazioniLocazioneFinanziariaLocatario" order="1" priority="0" use="optional"/>
  <presentationArc xlink:type="arc" xlink:arcrole="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/arcrole/parent-child" xlink:from="itcc-ci_ContrattiCorsoOperazioniLocazioneFinanziariaLocatario" xlink:to="itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziario" order="1" preferredLabel="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/periodStartLabel" priority="0" use="optional"/>
  <presentationArc xlink:type="arc" xlink:arcrole="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/arcrole/parent-child" xlink:from="itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziario" xlink:to="itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziarioRelativiFondiAmmortamento" order="1" preferredLabel="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/periodStartLabel" priority="0" use="optional"/>
</presentationLink>
<presentationLink xlink:type="extended" xlink:role="http://www.infocamere.it/itnn/fr/itcc/role/NotaIntegrativaAttivo">
  <presentationArc xlink:type="arc" xlink:arcrole="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/arcrole/parent-child" xlink:from="itcc-ci_ContrattiCorsoOperazioniLocazioneFinanziariaLocatario" xlink:to="itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziario" order="2" preferredLabel="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/periodEndLabel" priority="0" use="optional"/>
  <presentationArc xlink:type="arc" xlink:arcrole="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/arcrole/parent-child" xlink:from="itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziario" xlink:to="itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziarioRelativiFondiAmmortamento" order="1" preferredLabel="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/periodEndLabel" priority="0" use="optional"/>
</presentationLink>
```

The result should be

```
itcc-ci_AttivitaOperazioniLocazioneFinanziariaLocatario
  itcc-ci_ContrattiCorsoOperazioniLocazioneFinanziariaLocatario
    itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziario (periodStartLabel, order=1)
      itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziarioRelativiFondiAmmortamento (periodStartLabel, order=1)
    itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziario (periodEndLabel, order=2)
      itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziarioRelativiFondiAmmortamento (periodEndLabel, order=1)
```

**Is this the valid way to implements this hierarchy using presentationLink?**
I have trouble identify parent node for 'itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziarioRelativiFondiAmmortamento'.
Should I resolve parent for 'itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziarioRelativiFondiAmmortamento' using *presentationLink*s as different containters and **after** merge *presentationLink*s to build the complete or I have only to scan every *presentationArc* and refer to last parent found?

I have read a lot of docs and code but I still have a doubts about how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance to all for the answer.
I hope I was clear,English in not my native language.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to read the specifications.  Neither of your suggestions are likely to result in the correct answer.

You need to work out the [Network of Relationships](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html#_3.5.3.9.7.3) for this relationship type and role. A very high level summary:

1. group the arcs into 'base sets' and find the one for this network
2. find the equivalent relationships
3. remove any prohibited or overridden relationships

You might get away without 2 & 3 if there aren't any.  What you're left with is a bunch of relationships that describe this network which will allow you to build the tree.

If you have no idea what I'm talking about, then I'd strongly suggest using a 3rd party XBRL library.  The specs aren't written in the most straightforward manner, and the fact English isn't your native language won't make this easier.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I appreciated it a lot. I have read attached docs (and other paper) lot of times; now I have built  arcset for extended-link-role. steps 2 & 3 doesn't apply because equivalence and override are not presents. My concern is about tree creation for this specific situation because I can't find a good way to create desidered tree because two `BeniLeasingFinanziarioRelativiFondiAmmortamento` with start/end label are attached to `BeniLeasingFinanziario` periodStart and `BeniLeasingFinanziario` periodStart has not child. Any advice or link to point me to a good way?

Comment: Do you have the actual taxonomy files you can link to? From the snippet you've given I wouldn't expect the 'expected' result. Off the top of my head you'd have two `itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziarioRelativiFondiAmmortamento` children under *both* `itcc-ci_BeniLeasingFinanziario` parents, and the order of the children is non-deterministic.

Comment: Yes, I have all files. About your comment: running my code I have reached the same result you described (as I expected,too) and not the expected one. I thought presentation-links were wrong and seems you are comfortable to my idea.